# Datebox issue in zk

Tags: user-interface, calendar, zk, datebox, zul

I have a issue  given  below  regarding `datebox`  calender .When i use `width="150px"`  its working fine  and when i use `width="300px"`  the the calender not properly display (given image)but my requirement `width="300px"`  of `datebox` .

Anyone can give me any idea how can i resolve this issue .

[image]

Here's zul:

```xml
<datebox hflex="1" readonly="true" lenient="true"
    value="@bind(folderInfoData.folderInforecord.infoValueDateTime) "
    tooltiptext="@load(vm.getText('FolderInfoDetail:SELECT_DATE'))"
    mandatory="@load(folderInfoData.folderInforecord.valueRequired)"
    width="300px">
</datebox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this under the zk tag :

```
<style>
    div.z-calendar{
    width:429px;
    }
</style>
```

why 429px? because zk makes your box bigger than 300 px (you can inspect that with firebug)
Now you can choose how big your columns will go.

Greetz chill.